# How do these accounts differ from each other? tz1 vs tz2 vs tz3

Tags: account

Does anybody know what makes these accounts different?

I have noticed some bakers having tz2, tz3 accounts

What is the purpose and/or designation of **tz2** and  **tz3** accounts?